# foreach breaks and gives error when try to load this json

Tags: javascript

i am trying to load this json in my page but foreach break and gives error as the number is not in serial

if we provide the number in serial it works.
serial means in incremental
this is my json

```
{
    "": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "reply": "",
        "parent": "",
        "actions": []
    },
    "0": {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "",
        "reply": "",
        "parent": "",
        "actions": [
            "01",
            "02",
            "03",
            "04",
            "06",
            "07"
        ]
    },
    "01": {
        "id": "01",
        "name": "Order Status",
        "reply": "Please provide your order number",
        "parent": "0",
        "actions": [
            "011"
        ]
    },
    "07": {
        "id": "07",
        "name": "Book Appointment",
        "reply": "Book Appoinme",
        "parent": "0",
        "actions": []
    },
    "welcomeMssg": "Do you need help with :-",
    "startId": "0",
    "scName": "test name"
}
```

and this is my javascript

```
var scenario = "";
var fdata = null;

function getScenarioData(scid, cid) {
  scenario = scid;
  var obj = {
    client: cid,
    scenario: scid,
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getdata.php",
    data: obj,
    success: function (data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      fdata = data;
      console.log(fdata);
      document.getElementById("welcomeMessage").value = data.welcomeMssg;
      document.getElementById("scenarioName").value = data.scName;
      scenarioName = data.scName;
      welcomeMessage = data.welcomeMssg;
      start = data.startId;
      buttons = data;
      document.getElementById("main1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("entry").style.display = "none";
      ac = buttons[start].actions;
      for(let k in buttons) {
        if(buttons[k].actions){
          count[k] = buttons[k].actions.length+1;
        }
      }
      console.log(count);
      ac.forEach(e => {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.className = "replybox m-1 p-2 form-control";
        input.placeholder = "reply";
        input.style.display = "inline";
        input.value = buttons[e].name;  
        input.id = buttons[e].id;
        var id = buttons[e].id;
        input.onclick = function () {
            addRes(id, buttons[e].parent);
        };
     //   input.onkeyup = function () {
                input.onchange = function () {
            buttons[id].name = document.getElementById(id).value;
            if (document.getElementById("show" + id)) {
            document.getElementById("show" + id).innerHTML =
                "(for " + document.getElementById(id).value + ")";
            }
        };
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        var s = document.createElement("span");
        d.id = "reply"+id;
        s.innerHTML = `<i class='fa fa-times-circle circle' aria-hidden='true' onclick='deleteButton("${id}");' style='font-size:15px;cursor:pointer;margin-left:-10px;;'></i>`;
        d.appendChild(input);
        d.appendChild(s);
        document.getElementById("replies0").appendChild(d);
      });
  },
  error: function (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  },
 });
}
```

if i change the json output to 2 instead of 7 it works fine. i am confused is it mandatory to have data in incremental if we are using foreach

when i say if i replace 7 with 2 means this

```
"07": {
        "id": "07",
        "name": "Book Appointment",
        "reply": "Book Appoinme",
        "parent": "0",
        "actions": []
    },
```

here is live site for demo
https://way2enjoy.com/shopify/1/whatsapp-chat/bot/1/2/edit_scenario.php?client=50457

any help will be great

i get this error at console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at edit_scenario.js:39
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (edit_scenario.js:33)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: it works for other cases. where it is in incremental

Comment: in this part instead `for` use `foreach` : change this code to foreach
`for(let k in buttons) {
        if(buttons[k].actions){
          count[k] = buttons[k].actions.length+1;
        }
      }`

Comment: @AmirKhaledian how exactly. i tried it gives different types of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over `["01", "02", "03", "04", "06", "07"]` and try to access each of these keys on the returned object. Yet `data["02"]`, `data["03"]`, etc. do not exist, thus resulting in `undefined`.

> ```
> ac.forEach(e => {
>   // …
>   input.value = buttons[e].name;  
>   input.id = buttons[e].id;
>   var id = buttons[e].id;
>   input.onclick = function () {
>     addRes(id, buttons[e].parent);
>   };
>   // …
> });
> ```

In the above code `ac` refers to `buttons[start].actions` or simply put `buttons["0"].actions` which is `["01", "02", "03", "04", "06", "07"]`.

You then start iterating over these actions, trying to use each element as key to access the object. `buttons[e]` is `buttons["01"]`, `buttons["02"]`, etc. Since you only have the keys `"01"` and `"07"` present, all other attempts will result in `undefined`.

This produces an error because `buttons[e].name` -> `buttons["02"].name` -> `undefined.name` -> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".

This can be solved in three ways. Two of which are the responsibility of the server.

1. Client-side solution: Skip the elements if they are not present within the object.

   ```
   // Only select the actions that are actually present in `buttons`.
   ac = buttons[start].actions.filter(e => e in buttons);
   ```

   Or alternatively:

   ```
   ac.forEach(e => {
     // Skip the iteration if `e` is not present in `buttons`.
     if (!(e in buttons)) return;

     // …
   });
   ```
2. Server-side solution 1: Send only the actions to the client that are actually present in the response.

   ```
   {
     // …
     "0": {
       "id": "0",
       "name": "",
       "reply": "",
       "parent": "",
       "actions": ["01", "07"]
     },
     // …
   }
   ```
3. Server-side solution 2: Instead of reducing the actions you could also send all the related objects.

   ```
   {
     // …
     "0": {
       // …
       "actions": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "06", "07"]
     },
     "01": { /* … */ },
     "02": { /* … */ },
     "03": { /* … */ },
     "04": { /* … */ },
     "05": { /* … */ },
     "06": { /* … */ },
     "07": { /* … */ },
     // …
   }
   ```

Comment: thxxxx. i was thinking to do the same from server end. thxxxxxxxxxxxx a lot.